# Password Policy in ASP.NET Profile (Membership)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, password-policy

In change password page, we have this code, So if we want to change Password Policy into "StrongPolicy", have we a way or is it by default?

Also can we change it to weak policy ?

I read MSDN but couldn't find it.

```
Membership mu ; 
mu=Membership.GetUser(txtUserName.Text); 

mu.UnlockUser();
var newPass= mu.ResetPassword();
mu.ChangePassword(newPass,TxtPassword.Text);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the memebership provider in .net restricts you to have password of length 7(atleast) and of which one character must be alpha-numeric.

Although there many ways by which you can change that. You can check **[Changing password policy setting in membership provider.](http://weblogs.asp.net/pleloup/archive/2005/12/05/432359.aspx)**

Using minimum length and non-alphanumeric character

```
<membership ...>
  <providers>
    <add minRequiredPasswordLength=10 minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters=2 .../>
  </providers>
 </membership>
```

Using regular expression

```
<membership ...>
  <providers>
    <add passwordStrengthRegularExpression= 
                    "^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,10}$" .../>
  </providers>
 </membership>
```

The above code is from the same site.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using MVC 5 (possibly MVC4, havent checked).

Theres a nice easy way of changing this without changing the config. In your solution explorer, go to

'App_Start' > IdentityConfig

Here you will see a passwordvalidator, changing these settings will allow you to alter the complexity of passwords required for your site:

`manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 6,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
                RequireDigit = true,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireUppercase = true,
            };`

Comment: This is for ASP.NET Identity, not ASP.NET Membership.

Answer (score 1):

By default ASP.NET Membership enforces strong passwords. If you want to make it weaker, by changing the configuration settings in Web.config

```
<membership>
    <providers>
      <add passwordStrengthRegularExpression= "" .../>
      <add minRequiredPasswordLength=... minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters=2 .../>
    </providers>  
</membership>
```

MSDN

> By default, the ASP.NET membership providers enforce strong passwords.
>   For example, the SqlMembershipProvider and the
>   ActiveDirectoryMembership providers ensure that passwords are at least
>   seven characters in length with at least one non-alphanumeric
>   character. Ensure that your membership provider configuration enforces
>   passwords of at least this strength. To configure the precise password
>   complexity rules enforced by your provider, you can set the following
>   additional attributes:

More information :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649487.aspx